# Android Studio 3.3 не учитывает изменения в коде при установке приложения на смартфон

Tags: android-studio

После обновления на Android Studio 3.3 пропала возможность запускать приложение на смартфон (Shift+F10) для применения измененного кода приложения. Изменения можно применить только выполнив Make Project или Rebuild Project.

InstantRun отключен. В настройках запуска приложения, на вкладке Miscellaneous, снята галка Skip installation if APK has not changed

Смартфон Xiaomi MiA1 на Android 9

Как это поправить?